# Superscript underline moves up with text

Tags: html, css

I have HTML code something like:

```
<div id="blah">
   We have winner of 1<sup>st</sup> Tournament
</div>
```

with css

```
#blah{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

But this moves underline of st to top and it looks wierd. Is there any way that i can fix it using css only

Comment: Here is a quick jsfiddle for comparison: http://jsfiddle.net/UPUVN/

Comment: It looks OK for me in firefox. I see the same error you mentioned in chrome (both current versions under ubuntu 13.04)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's simple.
Try this:

```css
#blah sup{
display:inline-block;
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
padding-bottom:2px;//as per your requirement
}
```

Comment: I know this is old but it's one of the most recent comments I have found regarding this issue and I'm dealing with this for the first time today (Dec 2015).

Your solution is a start but it's not a enough to get it to look right cross-browser (incl. mobile). You'll still have to do browser specific tweaks with the padding and if your <a> tag is bold then you have IE & FF making the underline 2px but Chrome using 1px so already you're having to tweak padding + border per browser to fix that issue.

Comment: Making the `<sup>` inline-block makes it act independently now, causing it to wrap to the next line by itself if at the max width of its container.

Answer (score 6):

use `border-bottom` instead of `text-decoration` (If you have only one line of text)

```
#blah{
    border-bottom:solid 1px black;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:15px
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xUa8P/)**

Comment: This won't work if the text wraps. You would need to use display:inline

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use underline and not bottom border (they are different things), then the only typographically acceptable solution seems to be to use superscript glyphs instead of `sup` markup or CSS corresponding to it. You would do this with [`font-feature-settings`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings).

The bad news is that among fonts commonly installed on people’s computers, only a few fonts, like the so-called C fonts (Calibri, Cambria, Candara, Consolas, Constantia, Corbel) and Palatino Linotype, contain such glyphs. There are also some limitations in browser support (e.g., no support on IE 9 and older). Example:

```
<style>
.sup { 
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "sups";
  -moz-webkit-font-feature-settings: "sups";
  font-feature-settings: "sups";
}
</style>
We have winner of 1<span class=sup>st</span> Tournament
```

On the other hand, using this approach is safe in the sense that when the technique does not work, the rendering falls back to unstyled “1st” (with underline behaving normally).

Comment: This is a super old answer and with no votes. But this helped us so much. Thank you stranger from the past!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for me, as the border was sometimes offset with the underline, depending on the browser zoom and/or font size.

However, I did find a solution online that did not have this effect. It's all thanks to the comment left by "unruthless" @ https://gist.github.com/unruthless/413930 who credits Twitter user "chikuyonok". The user also provided a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/yyHNp/5/

The following is taken directly from the example linked above and works beautifully for me.

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, red, red 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, red, red 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, red, red 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(red), to(red));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, red 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(left, red, red 100%);
    background-position: 0 100%;
    background-size: 10px 1px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an underline at all but you want the superscript or trademark to be part of the anchor tag. here is what I did. I wanted the underline only on hover.

code:

```
a{text-decoration:none;}  a:hover .supS{text-decoration:underline;display:inline-block;}
```

Name title<sup>®</sup>Continued
AT&T Uverse<sup>®</sup>

link to demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sunnysak/2ttx5/

hope it helps someone

-S

Answer (score 0):

This may help, particularly if you are trying to override styles set by a framework, or unhelpful default browser styles:

```
#blah sup {
  position: static;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: super;
  font-size: 75%;
}
```

Obviously also with

```
#blah {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

as in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Just posted this elsewhere;

There is no easy solution to this problem (seems there's always a situation that requires some fiddling to fix).  I only needed 2px or 1px underline; 'u1' and 'u2'. While 'u' I kept as just {text-decoration:underline;}  (I like to keep it short and sweet)

(works with wrap).

HTML:

```
<span class="u2">
  Registered<sup>&reg;</sup>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.u2{
  border-bottom:2px solid #666666;display:inline;
}
sup{
  font-size: 40%;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sLtkx2qe/

Answer (score 0):

```
# sup {
display: inline-block
text-decoration: underline
}
```

Comment: You should also add some explanation of your code or maybe atleast some link from the docs etc.