# HTML: some browsers display link text containing CODE-Tag with interrupted underline

Tags: html

In HTML I'm trying to display links containing some monospaced characters (i. e. for program code) inside the text:

Example:

[behaviour for value="`47`"](http://example.com/somewhere.html)

```
<a href="http://example.com/somewhere.html">behaviour for value="<code>47</code>"</a>
```

On the screen (the browser has rendered the html) the underline is splitted (very ugly...). How to avoid this? Are there better style recommendations? I. E. in connection with representation of program code, like HTML elements or attributes...

New example (see communication with Malte):

```
<p>bla bla bla.</p>
<a href="http://example.com/somewhere.html">example for select statemens of <code>SELECT * FROM</code> type</a>
<p>These select statements are usually ...</p>
```

I do not want to avoid the underline. What I'm intending to avoid is the split of the underline. For some code examples it is even worse: the underline of the monospaced text is displayed at a lower position (vertical position on the screen) than that of the other text.

Another example:

```
<p>bla bla bla.</p>
<a href="http://example.com/somewhere.html">Effect of attribute <code>target="_blank"</code> in hyperlink tag A</a>
<p>These ...</p>
```

Added later:

[There seems a similar question at stackoverflow concerning superscript tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835280/superscript-underline-moves-up-with-text)

I used the example given there ([http://jsfiddle.net/UPUVN](http://jsfiddle.net/UPUVN/)) and it turned out that the underline is not splitted on IE and FF, but is splitted in opera. So we have a browser and browser version related problem. I will dig more in it tomorrow on my working station on client's side.

Comment: Say what now???

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: Sorry, perhaps really to generic.

Comment: If I want a continous line I have no idea why the line is interrupted. Has this something to do with some box characteristic?

Comment: <a style="text-decoration:none" href="http://example.com/somewhere.html">example for value="<code>47</code>"</a>

Comment: But then the underline is disappearing. All other links are displayed in blue characters with underline.

Comment: I do not want to avoid the underline. What I'm intending to avoid is the split of the underline. For some code examples it is even worse: the underline of the monospaced text is lower (vertical position on the screen) than that of the other text.

Comment: Eventually found a very similar problem: [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835280/superscript-underline-moves-up-with-text)

Comment: @Peter What do you think for that  example?? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16835357/4640991

Comment: @praguan That seems to be another example of the "similar problem" (see link above) - at least the example looks like the other one. I'll try this tomorrow and also testing the different browser versions (see my main question which I have extended). Thx and cu

Comment: @praguan Discussion continued at your answer "You should use css styling for your links ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use css styling for your links `<a></a>` tags, If you would like to avoid underline for the links:

```css
a{
text-decoration:none;
}

#blah{
    border-bottom:solid 1px black;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:15px
}
```

```html
<a  href="http://example.com/somewhere.html">example for value="<code>47</code>"</a>

<br/>
<div id="blah">
   <a href="#">We have winner of 1<sup>st</sup> Tournament</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This solves partly the problem: You get a solid line. Therefore I'll tick your answer as solved.

Comment: Disadvantage: You have to fix style of a-TAG (that is easy if you have a central css file) and you have to go through your code to introduce or modify div-TAGs. With these steps all your links will be displayed identically.

Comment: Another point to remark: The corrupt line seems to be browser dependent: Internet Explorer shows the different vertical positions, Firefox 38 also (but differently - other character in the link text like comma seem to have an additional effect), Firefox 45 does not show interruption.

Comment: Recently discovered that newer versions of browsers including opera does not show an interruption of line. On another internet explorer 11 also the interruption is not shown (perhaps some configuration issue like "compatible with..."?).

Comment: I think modern browsers are working properly and I'll try to convince my customer to switch to a modern browser. Older browsers may have some problem to decide which of the styles set have the higher priority.

Comment: For those who will continue to dig into the problem: Here my HTML for testing:

Comment: <p><a href="UebNach.html">Über <span style="text-decoration:none"><code>Nachrichten</code></span>, die<sup>kdk</sup> auf</a></p>
<p><span style="text-decoration:none"><a href="UebNach.html">Über <code>Nachrichten</code>, die<sup>kdk</sup> auf</a></span></p>
<p><a style="text-decoration:none" href="UebNach.html">Über <code>Nachrichten</code>, die<sup>kdk</sup> auf</a></p>
<p><span style="border-bottom:solid 1px black;display:inline-block;line-height:15px"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="UebNach.html">Über <code>Nachrichten</code>, die<sup>kdk</sup> auf</a></span></p>

Comment: Folks, I've discovered the code in my central fonts.css leading to the described problem with OLDER browser versions:

Comment: code {
    font-family:monospace,monospace;
    font-size : small;
    padding-left : 3pt;
    padding-right : 3pt;
}

Answer (score 0):

As your example is all Code the code tags should wrap all of the contents of the a-tag which is more the semantics side of it.

Comment: Malte, perhaps my example is bad due my limited knowledge of stackoverflow- functions. Let us use this example:

Comment: Could anybody help me to publish the code in correct format? A simple `code` seems not to work in comments ...